# InputConnection text committing

Tags: java, android, android-service

i have a simple `InputMethodService` implementation.
In my `Service` i have a `BroadcastReceiver`, that listens for events from my application.
My BR get scanned text and inserting it into current textfield (if my own soft keyboard is selected).
In my `broadcast receiver` i use the code below:

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
if (ic != null) {
     ic.commitText(text, text.length());
}
```

My broadcast receiver works fine, but on most devices text never inserted into the current textfield (into Chrome browser search field, or into text field in messages system application).
I see no errors in my logs, try catch block never triggered too.

#EDIT1
Seem like text committed into edittext-like fields. But never into web fields (input type). What could be the reason? How to insert text programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey. Seems like nobody know the answer.
But i found it myself.
After calling `commitText()` method you need to call `sendKeyEvent()` method on `InputConnection` object. Put key event into method with parameters: `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND`. That will trigger text inserting. Works both on applications text fields and web field.

Comment: I am getting an issue, I am initializing LocalBroadcastManager in onCreateInputView  and after barcode scan my boradcast receiver gets called but not able to set the barcode result into edit text .. could you please help me out

Comment: @param, guess I need more info to help you)

Comment: Please check my question I have mentioned my issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/56971234/3310181

Comment: Please have a look I have given the link for my problem